# android toolbar menu item clicks

Tags: java, android, listview, click, toolbar

So I have this 'add' item in my toolbar. This item is supposed to add views to a listView below the toolbar and it works when you press it the first time. However, once the first view is added you cannot add anymore. How do I fix this?

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.addButton) {
        final TextView noProject = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.NOPROJECT);

        final ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
        final ListAdapter addAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.list_item, R.id.listFrame, listItems);
        final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        lv.setAdapter(addAdapter);

        noProject.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        listItems.add("New Project");
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you are creating a new list and you are adding there only one item. 
You can try declaring your list as a field in your class.
Move this:

```
 final ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
```

out of your `onOptionsItemSelected`